# Multiple column lists from one <ul>, CSS and maybe a bit of JS

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists, multiple-columns

Look at my HTML code (let's say I have 100's of links in this manner):

<-- language: lang-html -->

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link5</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link6</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link7</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link8</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link9</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link.html">Link10</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you see it's one `<ul>` with many `<li>` inside.

**I would like this to look like this on page (5 columns):**

```
Link1  Link3  Link5  Link7  Link9
Link2  Link4  Link6  Link8  Link10
```

This URL has something similar explained: **http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/** however it causes different positioning of the links, *instead of listing going down, it goes to the right*, so the links end up looking like this:

```
Link1  Link2  Link3  Link4  Link5
Link6  Link7  Link8  Link9  Link10
```

I am not using any JavaScript framework on site, so I would like to have this done with only CSS and just a little of framework independent JavaScript.
Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The `column-count` property

To get the effect you are after, you can use [**`column-count: <number>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count):

> The column-count CSS property describes the number of columns of the
>   element.
>
> `<number>` Is a strictly positive integer describing the ideal number
>   of columns into which the content of the element will be flowed. If
>   the column-width is also set to a non-auto value, it merely indicates
>   the maximum allowed number of columns.

How the columns display is highly customizable, you can also configure column properties using: `column-width`, `column-gap`, `column-rule`, `column-rule-width`, `column-rule-style`, `column-rule-color`, `column-span`, `column-fill`, `columns` (see above linked MDN article)

### Demo

```css
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count: 5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link5</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link6</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link7</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link8</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link9</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/link.html">Link10</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using flex-wrap?

```
ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li{
    width: 20%;
}
```